# button value redirect to new page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Each product got individual “View product”  button

Button when clicked will get the individual product code as hidden value from db and redirects page along with the product code. I am using while loop to display individual product.

But my html not outputs as the button makes some errors

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { …
<input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">view product</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>   
$('#product_code').click(function() { 
    window.location = "2ndlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
      });
```

Comment: I think, you should create unique name for each button. So that click function can be bind to individual button.

Comment: what is `$("#product_code")` referencing? Because you have `name="product_code"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `id` must be unique for each element in your `while` loop

This will work for you

```
while ($row = $results - > fetch_assoc()) {…
<input name="product_code" class="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row[' product_code']}">
<button type="submit">view product</button>



<script>
$(document).on('click', '.product_code', function(e) {
  window.location = "2ndlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button has error Your double quotes not escaped

change below code:

```
<input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row['product_code']}">
    <button type="submit">view product</button>
```